# How to make line plot following histogram bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I am trying to make a hist plot with number of bins.
After that I want to draw a line plot following bins but I am not able to draw line plot. Can I get some help?

```
plt.hist(df1_small['fz'], bins=[-5, -4.5, -4, -3.5, -3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0, 0.5, 1,1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5])
sns.kdeplot(df1_small['fz'],fill=True, color = 'Red') 
df1_small['fz'].plot(kind = "kde")
plt.xlabel('Distribution of fz of small particles')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.show()
```

This is my code.
Plot I got is like this:

[image]

If you noticed, line plot is kind of straight line only in 0.

How can I draw line following all bins?

Data is here: https://github.com/Laudarisd/csv

Comment: The data at the link is gone, which is why do is supposed to be in the question, not a link to data. This is no long reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to trace the outline of [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), use the returned `counts` and `bins`:

```
width = 0.5
counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(data=df1_small, x='fz', bins=np.arange(-5, 5.5, width))
plt.plot(bins[:-1] + width/2, counts)
```

[image]

---

If you're trying to overlay a [`sns.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html):

- set `density=True` on the histogram to plot probability densities instead of raw counts
- `clip` the KDE to the histogram range
- lower the smoothing bandwidth factor `bw_adjust`

```
plt.hist(data=df1_small, x='fz', bins=np.arange(-5, 5.5, 0.5), density=True)
sns.kdeplot(data=df1_small, x='fz', clip=(-5, 5), bw_adjust=0.1)
```

[image]